# Queue and thread from file customize working threads

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, queue

I am planing to write a python script that reads urls from a file and checks the status code from these urls using requests. To speed up the process my intention is to use multiple threads at the same time.

```
import threading
import queue

q = queue.Queue()
def CheckUrl():
    while True:
        project = q.get()
        #Do the URL checking here
        q.task_done()
threading.Thread(target=CheckUrl, daemon=True).start()

file = open("TextFile.txt", "r")
while True:
    next_line = file.readline()
    q.put(next_line)
    if not next_line:
        break;

file.close()

print('project requests sent\n', end='')
q.join()
print('projects completed')
```

My problem. Now the code is reading all the text at once making as many threads as there are lines in the text file if I understand correctly. I i would like to do something like read 20 lines at the same time, check status code from the 20 urls, if one or more checks are done go to the next.

is there something like

```
threading.Thread(target=CheckUrl, daemon=True, THREADSATSAMETIME=20).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems i have to stick with this one

```
def threads_run():
    for i in range(20):  #create 20 threads
        (i) = threading.Thread(target=CheckUrl, daemon=True).start()

threads_run()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).